# "npm install express-generator -g" не устанавливается

Tags: node.js, express, nvm

```
nvm --version
➜ 0.35.2
➜  ~ nvm install 12.16.1
v12.16.1 is already installed.
Now using node v12.16.1 (npm v6.13.4)
```

Начинаю ставить npm install express-generator -g       - выбивает ошибку. Что уже делать не знаю(((

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modul
es'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'

npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the curre
nt user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Написано же, что недостаточно прав. Подозреваю права у тебя такие же

drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 ноя 20 11:51 node_modules

Вот решение на оригинальном стеке
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules-react