# Ошибки при установке React

Tags: reactjs

При npm install -g create-react-app выводится вот это
Не знаю что делать :(
Как это можно исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что за операционная система у Вас?

Comment: У вас нет прав создавать новые директории в 'usr/local/lib/node_nodules'

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: ["npm install express-generator -g" не устанавливается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1088576/); [При установки Npm/Gulp выдает ошибку!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1412735/)

Comment: 1) надо посмотреть версию npm (npm -v), обновиться до последней, возможно из-за этого не работает 2) можно поставить через [npx](https://sentry.io/answers/difference-between-npm-and-npx-in-javascript/). так советуют делать в [офицальной инструкции CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started).